# Failed to communicate with Braintree with taxamo checkout in magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, api

In Magento 2.1.2 configure taxamo site - set merchant and braintree   configuration in taxamo site & set test mode.

In **cart.phtml** page add script as below:

```
Taxamo.initialize('SamplePublicTestKey1'); //public key here

var transaction = { currency_code:'EUR',
transaction_lines: [{'custom_id': 1, amount: 1.99}] }

var metadata = { allowed_payment_providers: 'braintree',
require_invoice_address: true };

var checkout = new Taxamo.Checkout(transaction, metadata);
checkout.overlay(function(data) { //you can also use .redirect() here
alert('callbackhandler:' + JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'));
});
```

Add to cart any product then taxamo checkout form will open fill the details and click on proceed button.

But when fill up form and click on proceed button which throw error

> Failed to communicate with Braintree with taxamo checkout in magento2

Comment: Have you set Web API referer in Taxamo's JavaScript API page: https://dashboard.taxamo.com/merchant/app.html#/account/api/javascript ("To use our API on your pages through Taxamo.js , you need to add the domains which will be accessing it.")?